# Unable to create activity with wizard on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying to create and activity using the new->Activity wizard after filling necessary information the wizard just gets stuck. Clicking "finish" again shows this error

```
IllegalStateException: Invalid operation attempted after wizard already finished
```

[image]

I'm on windows 7 running Android Studio 2.3.1

Comment: This seems existinf issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37105723, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37132650

Comment: Yeah but this is 2.3.1 and that is 2.2(.3) thought it was fixed already

Comment: What is the question, though? If you simply want to report a bug then this is not the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following configuration from your project build.gradle and then clicking on sync now

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(); 
if (osName.contains("windows")) { 
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}" 
}
```

Close the project

Import the project again

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do one thing. 
Instead of selecting Blank/empty Activity you can go for **Gallery** option as shown below and this would avoid "Not Responding errors".

[image: Select from Gallery]

In the Gallery select empty/blank Activity and that should work.

However This Error was fixed in Android Studio 2.2 preview 4 as per the google update but seems to be still appearing on Android Studio 2.3.1.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37105723

Comment: And now return back in AS 2.3.3.

Comment: Also get this error in version 2.3. I have to kill Android Studio using Task Manager. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Java class and extend the Activity class. Then add that activity in your Android Manifest.